# how to edit window service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a window service that makes a task every 60 seconds and it worked fine but now I want to edit the time and make it 10 seconds but unfortunately it didn't work I tried to uninstalling and installing the service but didn't work either so how can I edit my window service?
I will put the code of on start method

I tried changing the value of the timer. interval but it didn't change the task still run every 60 sec not every 10 sec

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // Update the service state to Start Pending.
            ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
            serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart.");
            // Set up a timer that triggers every minute.
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds i want to change it to 10sec
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
            timer.Start();
            // Update the service state to Running.
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
        }
```

when i open my event viewer i see the events are added every 60 sec not every 10 despite that i have changed the timer value  so why is that

Comment: How did you replace the old service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, you have made the change and rebuilt the project but failed to deploy the service executable to the correct startup folder.  Go into Control Panel / Services and find your service.  Assuming it was properly registered, you will be able to right-click on it, select Properties and find "Path to executable" on the General tab.  Since you have done nothing to change the service interface, you should be able to Stop and Disable the old service and copy the new .exe over the old, Start and get the behaviour you're looking for.